# count number of records by month over the last five years where record date > select month

Tags: sql, ms-access

I need to show the number of valid inspectors we have by month over the last five years. Inspectors are considered valid when the expiration date on their certification has not yet passed, recorded as the month end date. The below SQL code is text of the query to count valid inspectors for January 2017:

```
SELECT Count(*) AS RecordCount
FROM dbo_Insp_Type
WHERE (dbo_Insp_Type.CERT_EXP_DTE)>=#2/1/2017#);
```

Rather than designing 60 queries, one for each month, and compiling the results in a final table (or, err, query) are there other methods I can use that call for less manual input?

Comment: Edit question to show sample data and desired output.

Comment: You show an international date structure which can be tricky in criteria. Review http://allenbrowne.com/ser-36.html

Answer (score 0):

| ID | Cert_Iss_Dte | Cert_Exp_Dte |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1/15/2020 | 1/15/2022 |
| 2 | 1/23/2020 | 1/23/2022 |
| 3 | 2/1/2020 | 2/1/2022 |
| 4 | 2/3/2020 | 2/3/2022 |
| 5 | 5/1/2020 | 5/1/2022 |
| 6 | 6/6/2020 | 6/6/2022 |
| 7 | 6/7/2020 | 6/7/2022 |
| 8 | 7/21/2020 | 7/21/2022 |
| 9 | 2/20/2020 | 2/20/2022 |
| 10 | 11/5/2021 | 11/5/2023 |
| 11 | 12/1/2021 | 12/1/2023 |
| 12 | 12/24/2021 | 12/24/2023 |

A UNION query could calculate a record for each of 50 months but since you want 60, UNION is out.

Or a query with 60 calculated fields using IIf() and Count() referencing a textbox on form for start date:

```
SELECT Count(IIf(CERT_EXP_DTE>=Forms!formname!tbxDate,1,Null)) AS Dt1,
Count(IIf(CERT_EXP_DTE>=DateAdd("m",1,Forms!formname!tbxDate),1,Null) AS Dt2,
...
FROM dbo_Insp_Type
```

Using the above data, following is output for Feb and Mar 2022. I did a test with Cert_Iss_Dte included in criteria and it did not make a difference for this sample data.

| Dt1 | Dt2 |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | 8 |

Or a report with 60 textboxes and each calls a DCount() expression with criteria same as used in query.

Or a VBA procedure that writes data to a 'temp' table.

Answer (score 0):

From this sample:

| Id | CERT_EXP_DTE |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-01-15 |
| 2 | 2022-01-23 |
| 3 | 2022-02-01 |
| 4 | 2022-02-03 |
| 5 | 2022-05-01 |
| 6 | 2022-06-06 |
| 7 | 2022-06-07 |
| 8 | 2022-07-21 |
| 9 | 2022-02-20 |
| 10 | 2021-11-05 |
| 11 | 2021-12-01 |
| 12 | 2021-12-24 |

this single query:

```sql
SELECT 
    Format([CERT_EXP_DTE],"yyyy/mm") AS YearMonth, 
    Count(*) AS AllInspectors, 
    Sum(Abs([CERT_EXP_DTE] >= DateSerial(Year([CERT_EXP_DTE]), Month([CERT_EXP_DTE]), 2))) AS ValidInspectors
FROM 
    dbo_Insp_Type
GROUP BY 
    Format([CERT_EXP_DTE],"yyyy/mm");
```

will return:

| YearMonth | AllInspectors | ValidInspectors |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-11 | 1 | 1 |
| 2021-12 | 2 | 1 |
| 2022-01 | 2 | 2 |
| 2022-02 | 3 | 2 |
| 2022-05 | 1 | 0 |
| 2022-06 | 2 | 2 |
| 2022-07 | 1 | 1 |